# object won't die (still references to it that I can't find)

Tags: python, logging, reference, garbage-collection, parallel-python

I'm using parallel-python and start a new job server in a function. after the functions ends it still exists even though I didn't return it out of the function (I used weakref to test this). I guess there's still some references to this object somewhere. 
My two theories: It starts threads and it logs to root logger.

My questions: can I somehow findout in which namespace there is still a reference to this object. I have the weakref reference. Does anyone know how to detach a logger? What other debug suggestions do people have?

here is my testcode:

```
def pptester():

    js=pp.Server(ppservers=nodes)
    js.set_ncpus(0)
    fh=file('tmp.tmp.tmp','w')  
    tmp=[]
    for i in range(200):
        tmp.append(js.submit(ppworktest,(),(),('os','subprocess')))
    js.print_stats()
    return weakref.ref(js)
```

---

thanks in advance
    Wolfgang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gc.get_referrers(obj)` to find out what is referencing the object. Because you'll most likely get a bunch of dicts as the response, you'll have to go up a couple of levels to make any sense of it.

Comment: that worked. found out that the package used atexit module. 
thanks for your help